# How to identify a book region in a photo

Tags: opencv

I have a photo of a book, like  this

[this http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/8981/photoexl.jpg](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/8981/photoexl.jpg)

and I want to get only the area of the book with OpenCV.

I've tried several methods: Canny, findContours, cvblobs... But I have no experience at all in the field, and I was wondering if there is an optimal method of doing it.

I can not make any assumption on the color of the background (excepting that it is different from the book).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using an algorithm based on SIFT or SURF, in order to detect and describe local features in images (like a book in this case).

One interesting implementation is [OpenSurf](http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html), which internally uses OpenCV for general computer vision functions.  I've used it this year for an image-based search engine (coincidentally, for the test cases  books where used).

Answer (score 1):

you can use CvFindContours, as result you get a list of all contours.
explore the list and look for the countours with more elements (points), then apply the function cvConvexHull (the contour will not be perfect, with that you discard some points and you get a convex region)
if it still does not work maybe you should add other contours retrived from the first function, but you need to check it by trting

Answer (score 0):

you can try this online designer
http://www.3p-publisher.com/index.php/id-3p-online-photobook-designer-photo-book-editor-print-business.html

Answer (score -1):

I think the contour of the book is the largest closed contour in the photo.